# generate resource URL within controller endpoint

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to minimize my API response bodies by replacing information about subresource with a resource URL. So let's say you would fetch a vendor and don't want to list all the products he is selling but you want to provide a URL that leads to those information.

For example I tried this in my controller endpoint

```
string resourceUrl = Url.Link(nameof(GetVendorById), new { id = 1 });
```

and was expecting to get the following string

```
https://localhost:5001/vendors/1
```

Unfortunately the string returns `null`. So how do you generate such resource urls?

The following dummy code is just an example of what I want to achieve, I know I shouldn't return the vendor products when fetching a vendor.

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<VendorResponseModel>> GetVendorById([FromRoute] int id)
{
    VendorResponseModel vendor = new VendorResponseModel()
    {
        Id = id,
        Name = "Vendor " + id,
        Products = new List<VendorProductResponseModel>()
        {
            new VendorProductResponseModel()
            {
                Id = 1,
                ResourceUrl = Url.Link(nameof(ProductsController.GetProductById), new { id = 1 })
            }
        }
    };

    return Ok(vendor);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to link to action in the same controller?

Comment: sometimes not, as shown in my code example I added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Url.Link` does work for me when tagging the resource method with a `Name` attribute. So when calling `Url.Link(nameof(GetVendorById), new { id = 1 });` I had to make sure that the `GetVendorById` method is named like so

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetVendorById")]
public async Task<ActionResult<VendorResponseModel>> GetVendorById([FromRoute] int id)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Generates a relative URL to your current request
//E.g you are on a page in a folder named vendors that contains index.cshtml, 
//create.cshtml, details.cshtml And the current request is on create.cshtml,
// the preceding code will generate a URL relative to your current url 
//{"baseurl/vendors/details/556"}
var resourceUrl = Url.Page("/details", pageHandler:null, 
        values: new { productId = 123, otherId = 556 }, protocol: Request.Scheme);

//Used normally for MVC controllers
Url.Action("yourAction", "yourController", new { myId =455}, Request.Scheme);

//Gets the URL of the current request
Url.ActionContext()

//Generates a URL with your base URL appended to it
Url.Content("~/tyuu/you/557")

//Generates an absolute URL 
Url.Link("routeName", new { myId = 456 }

//Then you can encode it this way
var encoded = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(resourceUrl)
```

Will give you the URL with all the parameters you want insides of it.
**Edit**
If you think the problem is the package itself, clean solution, remove all packages and `dotnet restore`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I debugged those approaches and this is the result https://hatebin.com/dqwhyqyncu so I think the problem is another. This is a fresh project, the controller inherits from `ControllerBase`

Comment: thanks for your edit. I found a solution for this and answered my own question. But maybe you know how to avoid naming the method because this seems to be redundant.